# How to find out the current session state (similar to WTSRegisterSessionNotification)

Tags: windows, winapi

I understand that the Windows (i.e Windows XP onwards) supports fast user switching, and in one machine it is possible that multiple users have logged in, but out of which only one user could be active.

I have used `WTSRegisterSessionNotification`, `WTS_CONSOLE_CONNECT`, and `WTS_CONSOLE_DISCONNECT` to get the active user, which works fine in most of the cases.

`WTSRegisterSessionNotification` would send the "Session change notifications" only when there is a "session change"(like user switch).

Instead of waiting for the "Session change notifications", can I know the "current session state"? Is there any api?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query session information with the [`WTSQuerySessionInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383838.aspx) function